# Running XDP code on a data processing unit

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

We are currently running XDP code in driver mode on the server's CPU, but we are evaluating new NICs, and we are considering running XDP code on a data processing unit (DPU). Instead of running the XDP code on the server CPU, we would run the code on the DPU's CPU. Our current XDP code (1) blocks traffic by filtering traffic using a BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH and (2) inserts flows into a BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF, which the application picks up and processes.

From what I see, there's not many resources for running XDP code on a DPU. Is this a valid configuration? Would this bring performance benefits? Would it be possible to run the XDP code in HW offload mode on the DPU, thus making the internals of the DPU transparent? If so, would running in offload mode have all flexibility of running on the server CPUs, such as tail calls?

Comment: It might depend on the specific DPU, I only looked at Nvidia DPU docs. Those seem to run ARM CPUs with linux on the DPU as control plane, from there you can program the specialized silicon with custom APIs (so no XDP) and you can tell it to send certain traffic to the ARM cores where you might be able to if there is driver support. These ARM cores are the slow path so not able to do line rate. To get the most out of the DPU you likely need to configure the custom proprietary silicon with custom proprietary SDKs.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the CPU on these DPUs wouldn't be able process packets as fast as a CPU on a server. Basically, whatever CPU on those NICs is not sufficient to handle whatever bandwidth the NIC advertises.

Comment: Found an image of Nvidia Bluefield architecture. The ARM CPU on the board is connected to the datapath, so it do some things. But for filtering or whatever at full line rate you will want to configure the connectX subsystem which doesn't use XDP to do so but these custom SDKs https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/bluefielddpuosv380/functional+diagram

Comment: But, the description also says that the mlx5 driver runs on the ARM side. So the ARM subsystem should be able to use XDP in driver mode there. But as stated, that doesn't use any of the special DPU features. But you should be able to use both at the same time or something like that. Again, depending on the processing power of the ARM cores

Comment: Thanks. From the arrow direction in diagram it seems like the CPU is only for provisioning the switch, not for reading packets.

Comment: Not sure the arrow is correct, yes it can do the config, but it also has network ports via the eSwitch according to other diagrams in the same docs https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/bluefielddpuosv380/kernel+representors+model